# Autofac - Register a (Partially) Open Generic.

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the Following configuration that I want to register in autofac:

```
UploadStrategy1<T> : IUploadStrategy<Thing1, T>
UploadStrategy3<T> : IUploadStrategy<Thing3, T>
......
```

Which is in a constructor like this

```
public class UploadDownloadHandlerStrategy1<T> : IUploadDownloadHandlerStrategy1<T, Thing1, OtherThing1>
{
   public UploadDownloadHandlerStrategy1(IUpoadStrategey<Thing1, T>, 
                                         IDownloadStrategy<Thing1, OtherThing1>)
}
```

This is one of those less than ideal situations where It really does have to be this messy. Actually I'm pretty proud I got it decoupled at all.

The only part I don't have working is the IUploadStrategy. So far there is about 8 Implementations, but It is supposed to scale up, so a bulk would be preferable.

I just cant figure out what thats supposed to look like in autofac.

```
builder.???
```

Comment: When you resolve `IUploadStrategy<Thing1, String>` you want `UploadStrategy1<String>` and when you resolve `IUploadStrategy<Thing2, String>` you want `UploadStrategy2<String>` ? (working sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwvait)

Comment: With Simple Injector you can simply call `container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IUploadStrategy<,>), typeof(UploadStrategy1<>));`, but I'm not sure if Autofac supports such scenario.

Comment: @CyrilDurand That partially gets me there, trying to get that to a point i can register it 'as many', instead of individually. I suppose I'll need a base class for that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'as many' ? You want to register all `IUploadStrategy` at once ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yeah, i dont want to individually register each one at a time. Not just to save lines, but so that when I add a new one it is automatically added. I have that working with the IDownloadStrategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine you have these types :

```
public class Thing1 { }
public class Thing2 { }
public class Thing3 { }

public interface IUploadStrategy<T1, T2> { }

public class UploadStrategy1<T> : IUploadStrategy<Thing1, T> { }
public class UploadStrategy2<T> : IUploadStrategy<Thing2, T> { }
```

When you resolve `IUploadStrategy<Thing1, String>` you want *Autofac* to return an instance of `UploadStrategy1<String>` and when you resolve `IUploadStrategy<Thing2, String>` you want an instance of `UploadStrategy2<String>`

You can do this by registering these types like this :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UploadStrategy1<>)).As(typeof(IUploadStrategy<,>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UploadStrategy2<>)).As(typeof(IUploadStrategy<,>));
```

By doing so *Autofac* will automatically take in consideration the constraint on `T1`.

So,

```
var s1 = container.Resolve<IUploadStrategy<Thing1, String>>();
Console.WriteLine(s1.GetType()); // will be UploadStrategy1 

var s2 = container.Resolve<IUploadStrategy<Thing2, String>>();
Console.WriteLine(s2.GetType()); // will be UploadStrategy2
```

will works as expected. See this dotnetfiddle for a live sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwvait

If you want to resolve these types automatically, you may consider using the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method. Unfortunately this method won't let you do what you want because it is not a `RegisterAssemblyGenericTypes` method. You will have to scan yourself your assembly. For example :

```
foreach (Type t in typeof(Program).Assembly
                                    .GetLoadableTypes()
                                    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                                                .Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
                                                        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IUploadStrategy<,>))))
{
    builder.RegisterGeneric(t).As(typeof(IUploadStrategy<,>));
}
```

The `GetLoadableTypes` method is an extension method located on `Autofac.Util` namespace, this is the method internally used by the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method.